# Convert from HTML::Template to PDF:FromHtml says invalid XML

Tags: html, xml, perl, pdf

I create an HTML file using HTML::Template. The resulting code is a valid XML/HTML (check against a xml validator). But while convert to pdf using PDF::FromHTML a message of "invalid token in xml file" is found.

Trying changing the first declaration line from doctype to xml, or supressing, but nothing works. XML::Simple, PDF:API2, XML::Writer are last version.

Ay idea what is happening?

```
# create template object and store to verify
   shout('s',"create template from $str_filepath") if ($bool_DEBUG);
    $str_mytemplate =  HTML::Template->new(filename => $str_filepath, case_sensitive => 0, no_includes => 1  ); 
    $str_mytemplate->param(\%strct_toreplace);
    $str_filepath =  envDir('temp').newID().'.html'; 
    shout('',"template created, storing to : $str_filepath") if ($bool_DEBUG);
    if (open(FILE, '>', $str_filepath)) {
        print FILE $str_mytemplate->output;
        close (FILE);
        }
# generate pdf from created file
    shout('p',"Creating PDF ") if ($bool_DEBUG);
    $pdf_this = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' ); 
    $pdf_this->load_file($str_filepath); 
    $pdf_this->convert( LineHeight => 10, Landscape => 1, PageSize => 'Letter', );    
    shout('p',"Display PDF") if ($bool_DEBUG);  
    print header(-type=>'application/pdf', -charset=>'UTF-8'); 
    print $pdf_this->write_file();
```

- $bool_DEBUG and shout(); are a variable and procedure to set and display messages while debugging mode.
- Html code generated via template: http://www.etoxica.com/examplecode.html
- Template used: http://www.etoxica.com/exampletemplate.tmpl
- Message displayed:

SECTION: Creating PDF
Software error:
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 19, column 13, byte 430 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
 at /home/grupo/perl/usr/share/perl5/PDF/FromHTML.pm line 141.

Comment: Please include the html, or create a [mcve] of html. We need to be able to try to help debug this.

Comment: Html generated via Template http://www.etoxica.com/examplecode.html

Comment: Did you look at line 19? What's character 13? Is it obvious how it is malformed?

Comment: Line 19 char 13 s the '!' in the comment <!-- proyecto --> in the template; or the '/' in tag </td> on resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Found the problem (I guess) ;)

Consider the following lines:

```
<td>
    Some line of data
    <br/>
    A second line of data
</td>
```

When try to be read by PDF::FromHTML it will send a message of malformed token in the 5th line, specifically on the slash '/' from `</td>` tag; BUT, that is not the problem, the problem is created by the `<br/>` tag inside the `<td></td>`.

If it is changed to `<br>` or `<br />` no error is found. I don't know if using `<br>` is a good html practice to xml compability, even is defined as it [w3c br semantic](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element).